# Jquery - Click event stops working after ajax and FormData

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, form-data

I am using FomdData to upload image to the server. The function is working fine, but after the first upload, I am not able to perform a second one. It seems that a click event is blocked. **#upload-image** exist on the page when the document is loaded, and it is not altered in any way after success. What is the issue here?

**EDIT**

Click event is working, but ajax stops working after the first upload.

```
$("#product-sell-search").on("click", '#upload-image', function() {

        var
            url      = $(this).attr('href'),
            fileData = $("#ocrFile").prop("files")[0],
            formData = new FormData();

        if(!fileData){

            alert('Please Sellect File');
            return false;
        }

        formData.append('ocrFile', fileData);
        // Added in order for server to recognize as post request
        formData.append("post", "post");

        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            dataType: 'script',
            cache: false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            data: formData,
            type: 'POST',
            success:function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                $.when($('#product-sell-search')
                        .find('input[name=ProductsSearch]')
                        .val(data.replace(/['"]+/g, '')))
                .then(function(){
                    $('#product-sell-search').trigger('submit');
                });

            },
            error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                alert('There was an error. Please try again');
            }
       });

        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Try to disable and re-enable the click handler, like this: `$("#product-sell-search").off('click').on("click"....`

Comment: Still doesn't work. It seems that click event is working properly and the problem is within the ajax.

Comment: you make another call (submit) in success of ajax call, that might be the reason?

Answer (score 1):

Why retrun false is there is your function is successful then it should return true.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to make the script work properly. I deleted the **dataType: 'script'** line, and I can make multiple uploads now on a single page load.